# Appending a value onto a pivot table from a different sized pivot table

Tags: sql, excel

I have two excel pivot tables, one is a table of constant characteristics. For example

`Name`    `char1`    `char2`    `char3`

The second is a table of an ongoing series of measured dimensions of `Name`

`Name`    `Date`     `meas 1`    `meas 2` etc.

I want to add `char1` on to the end of the second pivot table based on the common value `Name` for ease in graphing values from the second table. I don't think that vlookup will work and haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: The source for those pivot tables are in the same workbook or are they from outside?

Comment: They are from an Access query

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly your Access Query to Excel using **Power Query** or **Power Pivot** there you can manage the data model and create a relation between both tables using `[Name]` as key for the join. then when you insert a pivot table using as source the data model in the workbook it will show you all the related tables in the `Field List` and you can just select the fields that you want for you report. This is an example I wrote for another post but I think this can give you an idea.

[image]